# PreparedStatement doesn't replace placeholder for setBytes

Tags: java, postgresql, prepared-statement

currently i'm facing a strange problem with PreparedStatements in Java.

I'm generating a SQL-Statement with 9 parameters to store information into my postgres database (integer, timestamp with timezone, double, double, double, double, timestamp with timezone, timestamp with timezone and bytea).

The problem appears for the last column (the bytea formatted). I want to store an serialized object. The serialization works fine and with the same code i'm already storing the object into another table of a different database.

Here is (the important part) of the code that i'm using:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO archiv_database VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";
Connection con;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement;        
long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
byte[] data = KryoIO.kryoSerializeObjectToBytes(myObject);

GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

try {
        con = ResourcesHelper.getConnectionToPGDatabase("jdbc:postgresql://ipadress/db", "user", "password");
        preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        preparedStatement.setInt(1, 0);
        preparedStatement.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(millis), calendar);
        preparedStatement.setDouble(3, 0);
        preparedStatement.setDouble(4, 0);
        preparedStatement.setDouble(5, 0);
        preparedStatement.setDouble(6, 0);
        preparedStatement.setTimestamp(7, myObject.getValidFrom(), calendar);
        preparedStatement.setTimestamp(8, myObject.getValidUntil(), calendar);
        preparedStatement.setBytes(9, data);

        if(preparedStatement.toString().contains("?")){
            System.err.println("Statement still contains a ? and can't be executed");
        } else{
            int n = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Stored into " + n + " row(s).");
        }

        preparedStatement.close();
        con.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The statement is prepared correctly till the setBytes method is called. There the data is not placed into the statement. The placeholder still exists afterwards. I already checked the data with debug mode. The serialization works without errors and the byte[] is filled with data. Here is what the statement looks like after all 9 set Methods:

```
INSERT INTO archiv_database VALUES(0,'2015-11-10 11:19:24.430000 +01:00:00',0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,'2015-11-03 14:04:24.000000 +01:00:00','2015-11-03 14:07:04.000000 +01:00:00',?)
```

The statement itself is working. I already tested it via PGAdmin III by myself if i fill in some dummy data (null for the object). But as you can see the last placeholder still is there and not replaced even if the data variable holds data.

Maybe some of you have an idea how to solve the problem. If you need further information just ask for it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the field type and especially size? And what the length of `data`? Try a short array.

Comment: You realize that `if(preparedStatement.toString().contains("?"))` is a driver-specific hack, right? Moreover, it may not always work - specifically, consider what would happen if you bind a string variable with a question mark in its *value*.

Comment: The bytearray for the current test has a length of 346. But the storage is possible in an other project, too. So there shouldn't be a big problem with that.

I removed the check for the placeholder. I only added it to check if it always ends up there. The statement still not works.

Comment: What happens if you run `executeUpdate()` without doing the (useless) check for the the `?` - I'm pretty sure it will work. The assumption that the `toString()` method returns a String without `?` is plain wrong (and not sustained by any JDBC documentation)

Comment: I'm with a_horse_with_no_name, just execute the update, it'll probably work. The toString() method probably doesn't know how, or just doesn't want to output the byte[] data.

Comment: I know its useless. I added it after it didn't work anyway. Like commented a few seconds ago it doesnt change anything. The     executeUpdate() returns 1 now but i can't see the result in the database. So probably it stopped at the check sometimes wrong, good arguments of you. But im still confused why the result returns no error but the data isn't stored. And there is only one table with that name in the database.

Comment: Which Postgres version? Which driver version? This works just fine for me. It _sounds_ as if there is a commit missing in your code - although your sample code doesn't change the autocommit property.

Comment: I'm using driver version 9.4-1201-jdbc41 and postgres 9.4.4-3. The same versions are used in the other project where everything works fine...so i think this can't be the reason for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a_horse_with_no_name for the info about the commit. Seemed that the connection helper class i used from a colleague has no auto commit so i needed to call the     con.commit() method that everything is stored correctly.

Thanks for your help everybody :)